# Max function in Ant

Tags: ant, max

I have directories that creating by following pattern `build_yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS` 
i.e 
`build_20130304_112343142`
`build_20130402_102141121`

I need to determinate latest created directory in ant build

Does ant has some kind of max function?

Or perhaps you can propose me some another idea?

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [resources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html), i.e. echoing the latest created directory :

sort by name :

```
<resources id="foobar">
 <!-- default last count="1" -->
 <last>
  <sort>
   <name/>
    <dirset dir="path/to/rootdir">
     <include name="build*" />
    </dirset>
  </sort>
 </last>
</resources>

<echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>
```

sort by date :

```
<resources id="foobar">
 <!-- default last count="1" -->
 <last>
  <sort>
   <date/>
    <dirset dir="path/to/rootdir">
     <include name="build*" />
    </dirset>
  </sort>
 </last>
</resources>

<echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>
```

[Resource collections](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) came with Ant 1.7 and may be used in conjunction with `<copy>`, `<move>` .. etc.

Answer (score 1):

As your builds (and thus directory names) are effectively also ordered alphabetically then

`ls -rd | tail -n 1`

should give you the latest one.